# How to return custom error message when invalid value passed as entity type?

Tags: java, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an entity type that has a numeric property, and if the user of the API passes an invalid number for the property in their request, I get a 400 Bad Request JSON error (which is good) but in the message of the error, a stacktrace is shown. I would like to change this behavior so a custom message can be provided. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

A probable solution to fix this problem could be to use the Application Level Error Codes. It will indicate only one error on each case. For example, you could reserve error code 3,

```
   {
        “status _code”:400,
        “reason_phrase”:”JSON 400 error”,
        “error_code”: 3
   }
```

Status_code and reason_phrase fields would be helpful when someone is testing the API with a browser, client can find out what exactly is going wrong just by inspecting the error code field.

Another approach that could be befitting would be to use Resource Based Error Codes, you can use a string prefix tor each error code and that prefix is determined by the resource. For example:

```
   {
        “status _code”:400,
        “reason_phrase”:”JSON 400 error”,
        “error_code”:”big_error”
   }
```

To be able to provide the customized error message corresponding to the error code would be :

```
   {
        “status_code”:400,
        “reason_phrase”:”bad request”
        “Error_code”:”error_code_that_needs_be_handled_by_custom_message”
        “error_message”:”put the custom message over here”
   }
```

The code to handle the error with further information and clarification is provided in the following link and it will explain the Java handling error in detail. I am pretty sure it will help you out.

[Please check the following link for the code reference and the details to handle the error](https://alidg.me/blog/2016/9/24/rest-api-error-handling)

Thank you!

Comment: I guess my question is more specifically how to implement such errors in Google Cloud Endpoints. The general idea about application errors is exactly what I try to archive, but since the error does not get generated by my code (it's generated by the Google Cloud Endpoints API), I am wondering if it's possible to configure it such as application errors can be returned.

Comment: The error model is logically defined by google.rpc.Status, an instance of which is returned to the client when an API error occurs. Please check the following link for reference :).https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors

Comment: Hmm... I don't think we are talking about the same thing here. Google Cloud Endpoints is not the Google SDK -- read more here: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/   The links you provided thus far gives information about what I wanted to archive and how Google does it, but does not provide any information on how it can be configured in Google Cloud Endpoints.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, In that case would it be possible to check the following links, the links provide useful information regarding each and every error status code and how to configure the exception handling for them. :) https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/exceptions                      https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/exceptions  https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-response-errorshttps://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/troubleshoot-response-errors